# Access REST API running on server with self-signed certificate from android app

Tags: android, rest, api, ssl, https

I'm working on android app which is communicating with REST API on my server, which is self-signed. My API is running on node, using framework Loopback.

Right now, my API is not secured, so I can send requests from my android app and it works fine. Only my domain is secured. API running on port 3000. And now, the problem comes.

I have created a web form for password reset, so when user is in the app and wants to reset password for his account, he gets email. He can open this email with reset link either in the app or in a browser.

**1. case**

When user opens the reset link in browser, he is on HTTPS URL. When he enters new password and hits button to change the password, he is sending request from HTTPS to unsecured API on HTTP.

This gives me error:

`The page at xxx was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint xxx. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Here is my function:

```
function post() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const token = urlParams.get('access_token');
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);
    const user = {
        newPassword: document.querySelector('#input-password-check').value,
    }
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com:3000/api_path/reset-password')
    http.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', token)
    http.send(JSON.stringify(user)) 
    http.onload = function() {

        alert(http.responseText)
    }
}
```

**2. case**

When I secure my API so both, my domain and API are HTTPS, I could reset passwort from web, but when I send request, I get `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. And also from android APP, since it doesn't trust my certificate. And I was unable to find a solution how to make my app to trust it.

I should also say that I am parsing token from url and when reseting password in app, that token is sent in header and I send request from my app in java... Not opening website. All goes through retrofix + rxjava.

Any ideas how to solve this? I don't want to go around it, I want to do it right, but also not willing to pay for SSL certificate which will be trusted...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using Lets Encrypt certificates. Previously, I had lets Encrypt installed on my server but I created new, self-signed certificates for Loopback API, which was stupid and I did not know what am I doing.

So don't forget to set certificate path for loopback api to Lets encrypt ones.